# c# list with json content shows invalid Greek characters

Tags: c#, json, serialization

```
private List<payload> items()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("URL Site");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            request.AddHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
            var body = @"{

                some parameters.....
            }";
            request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;
            settings.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("el-GR");
            
            var ksite = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content, settings);
            JObject ob = JObject.Parse(ksite.ToString());
            JToken dataArray = ob["rows"];

            List<payload> item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<payload>>(dataArray.ToString());

            
            return item;
        }
```

My problem is that the list I getting from the endpoint shows invalid characters instead of Greek. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua0ea.png)

Comment: What does the raw JSON response look like? `response.Content` itself before deserialization.

Comment: Well, the Raw content has Greek characters. When I use it in postman, everything seems ok. But as soon as I get the response.Content instead of Greek characters I am getting this.

Comment: You have a second deserialize call `List<payload> item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<payload>>(dataArray.ToString());
` which is not taking in your CultureInfo, you will need to pass the settings into the second call as well. You also shouldn't need to do the deserialization twice if you deserialize into a pre-defined object.